# Should information about the experience level of the poster be edited out when reviewing?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we remove “I'm a newbie so please help me” lines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97620/should-we-remove-im-a-newbie-so-please-help-me-lines)

I some times see phrases such as "I am a newbie", "I am new to xyz" or "Please provide a simple answer" in questions I am reviewing. On the one hand, it feels relevant to the quality of answer that is required, on the other hand, it does not add much to the question. So, should such phrases/instructions be left in the original post or edited out?

Comment: @JoshCaswell, so it seems. Strange, I didn't find it when I searched. Should I just delete my question?

Comment: @Dhara - leave it around, it'll help more people find it later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally would (and often do) edit it out.

If the user is new to a certain topic, the subject matter will most likely indicate that. And we're looking for good answers. If the OP does not understand the answer given, he can always ask for clarification in a comment. The request for "a simple answer" to me is therefor noise.